# Pandas: check rows for columns division match with rounding

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding

Suppose I have a DataFrame `df` as

```
 A       B    r
145    146    99.32
1      10     10
2      20     35
```

The column `r` is meant to be the ratio of `A` to `B`, except for cases like the third row. But, as you can see, this ratio in first row has been rounded.

If I run

```
df[df.A/df.B == r]
```

I don't catch any rows because of the rounding. Obviously I could construct the column with the division, round it and then do the comparison, but is there a way to do this directly from the selection instruction above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [np.isclose()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) method:

```
In [32]: df
Out[32]:
   A  B          r
0  3  7   0.420000
1  3  7   0.428571
2  1  2  10.000000

In [33]: df.A/df.B
Out[33]:
0    0.428571
1    0.428571
2    0.500000
dtype: float64

In [34]: np.isclose(df.A/df.B, df.r)
Out[34]: array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [35]: np.isclose(df.A/df.B, df.r, atol=1e-2)
Out[35]: array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [36]: df.loc[np.isclose(df.A/df.B, df.r, atol=1e-2)]
Out[36]:
   A  B         r
0  3  7  0.420000
1  3  7  0.428571

In [37]: df.loc[np.isclose(df.A/df.B, df.r)]
Out[37]:
   A  B         r
1  3  7  0.428571
```

It's pretty flexible - you can specify relative or absolute tolerance:

> **rtol** : float
>
> The relative tolerance parameter (see Notes).
>
> **atol** : float
>
> The absolute tolerance parameter (see Notes).
>
> **equal_nan** : bool
>
> Whether to compare NaN’s as equal. If True, NaN’s in a will be considered equal to NaN’s in b in the output array.